# Replace a char within a pattern with sed

Tags: php, sed

I'm trying to change to migrate my php code using ZF1/PEAR convention to namespaces.

So I want is to change

```
$locale_test = (new ACME_Common_Factory())->createLocale(ACME_Common_Enum_Civility::MR);
```

to

```
$locale_test = (new \ACME\Common\Factory())->createLocale(\ACME\Common\Enum\Civility::MR);
```

I've tried using the following sed program (which would work for lines containing only 1 class name)

```
sed -r '/ACME/{h;s/ACME_.*$//1;x;s/^.*(ACME.*)$/\\\1/;s/_/\\/g;x;G;s/\n//1}'
```

But it actually does little more than

```
sed -r '/ACME/s/_/\\/g'
```

I would prefer a solution using sed or awk (just for the sake of improving my cli skill) but any other solution will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces as well as most special characters (but, crucially, not `_`) end a word, so I believe the word boundaries should serve well to identify class names. So, using GNU sed:

```
sed 's/\>/\n/g; :a s/\<\(ACME[^\n]*\)_\([^\n]*\)/\1\\\2/; ta; s/\<ACME/\\&/g; s/\n//g' filename
```

This works as follows:

```
s/\>/\n/g
```

puts newlines after closing word boundaries. We use this later to match (sort of) non-greedily. After this step, your line becomes

```
$locale_test
 = (new
 ACME_Common_Factory
())->createLocale
(ACME_Common_Enum_Civility
::MR
);
```

This leaves us with an easy way to identify names in the ACME namespace: `\<ACME[^\n]*`, and to identify names in the ACME namespace that contain an underscore: `\<ACME[^\n]*_[^\n]*`. We can use this to find underscores in ACME names and replace them one by one:

```
:a                                      # jump label for looping
s/\<\(ACME[^\n]*\)_\([^\n]*\)/\1\\\2/   # Attempt replacement
ta                                      # if it happened, go back to a.
```

After that, it's just

```
s/\<ACME/\\&/g
```

To put the `\` in front, and

```
s/\n//g
```

To remove the newline markers we put there.

Mind you, I suspect that this would be easier in Perl.

Comment: For some reason this is not working on my test file. Nothing is changed

Comment: Guessing: are you using Mac OS X? If not: Does it work if you replace all instances of `\<` and `\>` (there are three of them) with `\b`?

Comment: Odd. Works for me on Debian, with GNU sed 4.2.2. You didn't leave in the `-r` or anything? It's probably something along those lines; Debian and Ubuntu are very similar. I see no reason why a sed script that works on Debian should fail on Ubuntu, unless (perhaps) they were of very different ages.

Comment: My bad it works. I forgot to replace ACME with the real name xD. I'll accept your answer as you were first but it seems that mine is simpler and achieve the same result. Am i missing something?

Comment: My checks are stricter. Yours will handle all class names that contain `ACME`, as in `NotACME_foo_bar`, `Not_ACME_foo_bar` or even `Holy_Mackerel_Batman_They_Misspelled_NotACMECorp_On_This_Box`, albeit only the part that comes after the `ACME`, resulting in `Holy_Mackerel_Batman_They_Misspelled_NotACMECorp\On\This\Box`. It'll also not insert the opening backslash.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/(ACME[a-zA-Z\\]*)_/\1\\/;ta;s/ACME/\\&/g' file
```

Comment: nearly the same for me but adapt the last s to `s/le(ACME/le(\\ACME/` to limit on last *ACME*  (maybe bigger surrounding pattern, depending of rest of lines)

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
sed -r -e '/ACME_[^\(:]*/s/_/\\/g' -e 's/(ACME\\)/\\\1/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found an answer inspired by @Wintermute

```
sed -r ':a s/(ACME[^;:\(]*)_([^;:\(]+)/\1\\\2/g; ta' file
```

Comment: Note that this will also change `NotACME_foo_bar` to `NotACME\foo\bar` (and not add the first backslash before `ACME`).